# Win8 XAML Grid which column and row was tapped

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

In a windows store app I have a grid with a lot of columns and rows

```
        <Grid x:Name="gridContainer" 
              Background="Transparent"
              Tapped="gridContainer_Tapped">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                ...
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                ...
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       </Grid>
```

and listening to Grid Tapped event.

```
private void gridContainer_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Is it possible to determine which column and row was tapped without adding additinal transparet elements and tracking their tapped events?

Comment: You are giving the tap event for entire grid then how do you get the which row tapped?? are you binding any data for that rows and columns??

Comment: "You are giving the tap event for entire grid then how do you get the which row tapped?" I asked exactly the same question ...

Comment: i think that's only possible if you get coordinates of tap input on the grid and measure that with coordinates of Grid and it's row-columns..! Other than that, i'm not seeing any possibility..

Comment: I solved my problem by adding invisible controls and listenting to their Tapped event, but still think it will be very helpful if the Grid.Tapped EventArgs has the tapped Column and Row :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have anything inside those cells you can do this:

```
private void gridContainer_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.OriginalSource is FrameworkElement)
   {
      var col = Grid.GetColumn(e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement);
   }
}
```